# Как работает SSH с private key файлом?

Tags: linux, сеть, ssh, ssh-key, ssh-agent

Насколько я понимаю, ssh, упрощено работает таким образом:

1. Сервер отправляет свой публичный ключ для установления доверия или проверки соответствия, в случае наличия прошлых подключений
2. Создается симметричный общий ключ с помощью публичных ключей обоих.
3. Клиент отправляет свой публичный ключ для проверки наличия его в authorized_keys
4. Если ключ найден, то шифрует какой-то секрет публичным ключом клиента.
5. Клиент расшифровывает приватным и отправляет секрет серверу, который тот проверит.

Но в случае, допустим, .pem файла, которые выдает тот же амазон, содержится оба ключа, но на машине, к которой нужно присоединиться нет публичного ключа той машины, которая хочет присоединиться, как в этом случае действует ssh? Просто пропускает вторую часть 3-его шага?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Насколько я понимаю, ssh, упрощено работает таким образом:

Всё не совсем так:

0. Сначала Происходит обмен версиями серверов и поддержкой криптографических алгоритмов.
1. Обмен ключами по схеме [Диффи — Хеллмана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). Не расписывая подробности, это генерирует общий секрет `K` для обоих узлов. При этом используются только *эфемерные* ключи (т.е. те, которые используется только для получения общего секрета, а затем сразу уничтожаются) и не нужна отправка секрета по открытому каналу.
2. На основе секрета (`K`), а также некоторых других данных, известных обеим сторонам генерируется сеансовый ключ `H`, который сервер подписывает *своим приватным ключом* и отправляет эту подпись (`HS`) и свой публичный ключ клиенту.
3. Клиент проверяет публичный ключ сервера по своей базе или каким-либо другим способом, а также что `HS` подписана именно ключом сервера и, если что-то пошло не так, то выводит сообщение и отключается.

Всё дальнейшее общение сервера и клиента шифруется ключом `H` (точнее прикладными симметричными ключами, полученными на его основе).

4. Далее сервер предлагает клиенту методы аутентификации (в зависимости от настроек): по ключу, по паролю и т.п.
5. Если клиент выбрал аутентификацию по ключу, то он отправляет свой публичный ключ, а также подписывает своё сообщение приватным ключом.
6. Сервер проверяет подпись сообщения присланным публичным ключом, а также проверяет наличие этого ключа в своей базе данных (`authorized_keys`) и принимает решение, разрешить соединение или нет. Если нет, то он может предложить другой метод аутентификации; например, по другому ключу или паролю.

т.е. есть следующие важные отличия:

- И пара ключей сервера (в `/etc/ssh/`) и клиентская (в ~/.ssh/`) используется только для *аутентификации* и **не** используется для шифрования, как такового.
- Для установки защищённого соединения используются прежде всего эфемерные ключи, сгенерированные в момент установки соединения и уничтожаемые сразу после этого.
- Пересылка секрета не происходит. Каждый узел генерирует его самостоятельно.
- Для своей аутентификации узел **подписывает** некую строку своим приватным ключом, а вторая сторона проверяет эту подпись. Проверка шифрования не происходит.

---

#### Полезные ссылки

- [Неплохая статья](https://goteleport.com/blog/ssh-handshake-explained/) по начальному рукопожатию ssh ([перевод](https://miran.ru/rukopozhatie-ssh-prostymi-slovami))
- [RFC4552](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4252): Протокол аутентификации SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Шаг 3 не ограничивается аутентификацией по публичному ключу. В конфигурационном файле сервера `sshd_config` есть опции, определяющие разрешенные методы аутентификации.

Цитата из [`man sshd_config`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html):

> The available authentication methods are: "gssapi-with-mic", "hostbased", "keyboard-interactive", "none" (used for access to password-less accounts when PermitEmptyPasswords is enabled), "password" and "publickey".

На большинстве серверов разрешены методы `publickey,password,keyboard-interactive`. В этом случае если публичный ключ клиента серверу неизвестен, то он перейдёт к следующему методу аутентификации и запросит пароль пользователя.

В Амазоне по умолчанию запрещены все методы кроме `publickey`. В этом случае если у пользователя нет ключа, который знает сервер, то сеанс создан не будет.

Пункты 4 и 5 вашего вопроса я не понял.